# can I use the libnfc for any (different manufacturers) NFC reader module?

Tags: nfc, lib-nfc

I want to use the NFC reader with i-MX6 based custom board which is running on linux kernel.The module I have is AMS AS39111B .I want to access this module using C programming thats why I was searching the API ? I found libnfc.Now, my question is can I use the libnfc for accessing this module?
I got this question while I browsing this link  http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Devices_compatibility_matrix .